# getRange array filtering on gsheets for custom menu

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am trying to create a custom side menu to use as a filter and edit tool for data on the spreadsheet. I have the html and css down but Ive hit a snag on filtering array data from getRangevalues filtering.

```
  {
const {google, containeranalysis_v1alpha1} = 
 require('googleapis');
 const keys = require('./key.json');

 const client = new google.auth.JWT(
keys.client_email,
null,
keys.private_key,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
 );
```

async function gsrun(cl){

```
const gsapi = google.sheets({version:'v4', auth: cl});

const opt = {
    spreadsheetId: 'XXXXXXXX',
    range: 'Data!A1:G'
};

let data = await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get(opt);
let dataArray = data.data.values;
let newArray = dataArray.filter(function(checkDate){
    return checkDate === '09/16'; });

console.log(newArray);
 };
```

I am just trying to get a functional filter and then my next goal is to apply the filter parameters via html datePicker menu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBucT.png)

*Edit| this is my script I was working on in node.j using an api. no appscript, but is essentially the same

I am still having trouble getting the array to function after applying the filter.  im not getting any errors but i am also not getting  any return values.

Date    Patient Name    PO  Claim Submitted Frame   Lens    Status
09/15   xxxx    xxxx    PP  Yes No  Lens on Order
09/15   xxxx    xxxx    Yes         Lens on Order
09/13   xxxx    xxxx    PP  No  No  Frame & Lens on Order
09/16   xxxx    xxxx    Yes         Frame & Lens on Order
09/16   xxxx    xxxx    Yes         Frame & Lens on Order
09/16   xxxx    xxxx    Yes Yes No  Lens on Order
09/16   xxxx    xxxx    NA  No  No  Frame & Lens on Order
09/21   xxxx    xxxx    Yes No  No  Frame & Lens on Order
09/12   xxxx    xxxx    PP  Yes No  Lens on Order

this is the sheet.   I am trying to filter this by date and then return all entire rows meeting the criteria

Comment: What is your sample image? And, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling a 2d array properly.

```js
const dateColIndex = 0;
let newArray = dataArray.filter(function(row){
    return row[dateColIndex].getTime() === new Date('2021/09/16').getTime(); });
```

Comment: ok that makes much more sense.  Forgive me for my lack of knowledge.  I am relearning alot of things from school that I just never had a practical use for until now.

Comment: 1 other question.  When i console.log(newArray)  i don't actually get an output and am curious if I either have it coded wrong or not defining specifcally enough to output the array.  Would you be able to tell me what I am missing here after I applied the code above? basically I just want the out put to be the entire array of a row that match index[0] of what ever the date i apply for the filter

Comment: I guest your Column A is not a `string` but a `date` that you may need to do comparison between dates. Please find my updated answer.